# python modulefinder : relative importpath too deep

Tags: python, module

I write a simple code using modulefinder as dump_mod.py

```
import sys
from modulefinder import ModuleFinder

finder = ModuleFinder()
arg=sys.argv[1]
finder.run_script(arg)

print('Loaded modules:')
for name, mod in finder.modules.items():
    print('%s: ' % name, end='')
    print(','.join(list(mod.globalnames.keys())[:3]))
```

to dump the following script's imported modules (test.py)

```
import types
from functools import wraps
from . import PidFile
```

I got the following error saying:

```
#./dump_mod.py ./test.py  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./dump_mod.py", line 13, in <module>
    finder.run_script(arg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/modulefinder.py", line 110, in run_script
    self.load_module('__main__', fp, pathname, stuff)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/modulefinder.py", line 304, in load_module
    self.scan_code(co, m)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/modulefinder.py", line 399, in scan_code
    parent = self.determine_parent(m, level=level)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/modulefinder.py", line 145, in determine_parent
    raise ImportError("relative importpath too deep")
ImportError: relative importpath too deep
```

I know it comes from "from . import PidFile", how can I ignore this error and return the right import moudles except the line "from . import PidFile"

Comment: Did you use `try, except` for importing the module?

Comment: I can't find a place to use try, except, since it's in the "ModuleFinder" which is a standard libary